# Is Debian + Jetty a good combination?

Tags: web-applications, jetty, debian

I'm developing an GWT RPC service. Now I want to deploy it to a server. I was thinking about Jetty running on a Debian machine. Is this a good choice? Has anyone of you tried this combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty good combination.

- GWT on Jetty is pretty normal (Google use Jetty for their App Engine) http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/08/google-chose-jetty
- Jetty on Linux is pretty normal - most Jetty users would be running some flavour of Linux (including me).
  The jetty developers run Jetty 7 on Linux for their website: http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://www.webtide.com

Other combinations, and other Linux distributions will work well too, but your choice is a good one.